# Laravel @foreach

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I need to get each comment of news . Its working good for firstorFail() item

```
{{$news->comments()->firstOrFail()->name}}
```

But bring me empty result when im try this one with foreach:

```
 @foreach($news->comments() as $comment)
      {{$comment->name}}
      @endforeach
```

Comment: write only {{ $news->comments()->firstOrFail() }}

Comment: i need to get each comments name from foreach

Comment: do one thing echo $news->comments()-count();

Comment: its returned me 2.

Comment: You are in blade template so print array inside foreach loop as <?php echo '<pre>'; print_r($comment); ?> and see are you getting any key named **name**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This: `$news->comments()` bringing you query builder probably. So what you need is to `->get()` for execute query like this:

```
@foreach($news->comments()->get() as $comment)
    {{$comment->name}}
@endforeach
```

**Edit**

or as a @Roy Philips mentioned: `$news->comments`

Comment: Or he can use eager loading on his model and just do @foreach($news->comments as $comment)

Answer (score 1):

The function firstOrFail will return exactly one comment. Seems like you actually want all comments? You should use this in your controller

```
$news->comments; // yeah that's it, it will load all comments
```

Also return news

```
return view('my.view', compact('news'));
```

Then use it in blade

```
 @foreach($news->comments as $comment)
   {{$comment->name}}
 @endforeach
```

the line

```
$news->comments()
```

would require you to also call ->get() , because comments() will return the relation instead of the actual data.